# DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty doens't work anymore in NET 4.0

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, dependencies, propertydescriptor

I'm migrating some own built 'framework' dll's and I'm experiencing unexpecting behavior. I've stripped down the problem to the following:

I've got a custom combobox with a dependency property

```
Public Class MyCombobox
Inherits ComboBox

Public Property MyString As String
    Get
        Return CInt(GetValue(MyStringProperty))
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As String)
        SetValue(MyStringProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared ReadOnly MyStringProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyString", GetType(String), GetType(MyCombobox), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata())

End Class
```

When I call this code:

```
Dim descriptor As DependencyPropertyDescriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(MyCombobox.MyStringProperty, New MyCombobox().GetType())
```

This returns

In .NET 3.5 -> A valid PropertyDescriptor

In .NET 4.0 -> Nothing, Niente, Nada, Null

Is this a bug in the .NET framework? Has it become deprecated? Do I have any other options to get to the descriptor?

Comment: If anyhow possible do not use DependencyPropertyDescriptor. Just don't

Comment: Unfortunately, this is legacy code. I'll need to convert it